# Getting error as Segmentation fault (core dumped) while running npm run main

Tags: node.js, google-maps, npm, node-modules

I am new to Node.js and trying to implement the transport tracker from Google developer Codelabs steps link: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/transport-tracker-backend/#2 .

I am facing error **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** when I run `npm run main`.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "transport-tracker-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The server component for Transport Tracker",
  "scripts": {
    "main": "node main.js"
  },
  "author": "Brett Morgan",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "asyncawait": "^3.0.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "csv-parse": "^4.12.0",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
/*eslint-disable unknown-require */
const _async = require('asyncawait/async');
const _await = require('asyncawait/await');
const {GTFS} = require('./gtfs.js');
const gtfs = new GTFS();

_async(() => {
  const trips = _await(gtfs.getTripsForCalendarDate('20160518'));
  console.log(trips.length);
})().catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

It is the npm and nodejs conflict.

Try `npm rebuild`

if not

try remove nodejs

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

Then

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then install npm and nodejs back.

Comment: I have a recently installed Node v12 on ubuntu 21.10, but my project need a node v10. so I decided to uninstall the v12 and use an NVM to install a node v10, so after I have installed it, i have encountered this error while running npm -v, so I just run 

```sudo apt autoremove``` then ```npm rebuild```. now it works fine

Comment: FYI: `npm rebuild` was not enough in my case. `apt remove nodejs; apt autoremove; npm rebuild` was. Thx a lot!